# How do I block cookies just on Medium.com?

Tags: safari, cookies

Pardon the interruption.

Medium is tracking me and I don't care about Medium. How can I block their cookies in Safari?

Comment: As the OP doesn‘t care about medium.com, blocking the whole site (which is not the same thing as not going there, because it will prevent tracking cookies as well) as described in the answer to the linked question actually solves their problem.

Comment: No. The other article blocks web sites not cookies.

Comment: You can block cookies from web site with the Firefox browser. preferences > privacy   look for allow cookies.  look to the right on exceptions. click.  block cookies.

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but perhaps close enough. https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/2pzx26/is_there_a_safari_extension_that_will_block/

Comment: Please clarify, do you want to block Cookies or prevent Tracking.

Comment: Fabulous cookie management for macOS: https://cookie5app.com